# geom_segment not recognising factored x-axis

Tags: ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-segment

Aim: produce a bar plot representing a time series of measurements (variables) taken at 14 Sites (factors), including drawing horizontal lines to demonstrate benchmark levels for each site.

Problem: As the site labels are discrete and not quite a continuous series, i had to factorised the sites in `ggplot` mapping. However, when attempting to use `geom_segment` to add the benchmark lines, they are shifted in the same way the bars were drawn prior to factorising the sites. But, `as.factor` doesn't work in the mapping of `geom_segment` in the same way as `ggplot` mapping. Please help.

ive checked another similar question and tried both solutions: [Order of x-axis with geom_segment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56604329/12313457)

neither `+ scale_x_discrete(limits = levels(m_df$sites))` or

`+ scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)`

Data:

```r
df <- tibble(
  sites = c(2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17),
  T1 = c(6, 2, 4, 7, 8, 6, 2, 4, 7, 8, 6, 2, 4, 5),
  T2 = c(8, 5, 6, 8, 9, 8, 5, 6, 8, 9, 8, 5, 6, 8),
  T3 = c(4, 1, 6, 3, 4, 4, 1, 6, 3, 4, 4, 1, 6, 3),
  Le = c(6.0, 2.7, 5.3, 6.0, 7.0, 6.0, 2.7, 5.3, 6.0, 7.0, 6.0, 2.7, 5.3, 5.3)
)
```

## Melt the dataframe

```r
m_df <-  reshape2::melt(
  df,
  id.vars = c("sites", "Le"),
  variable.name = "Year",
  value.name = "value"
)
```

## plot the bar chart - black lines are shifted

```r
ggplot(m_df, aes(as.factor(sites), value, fill = Year)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "dodge",
           colour = "black") +
  geom_segment(aes(
    x = sites - .45,
    xend = sites + .45,
    y = Le,
    yend = Le
  ),
  colour = "black")
```

[image]

## I tried factorising which didn't work

```r
ggplot(m_df, aes(as.factor(sites), value, fill = Year)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "dodge",
           colour = "black") +
  geom_segment(aes(
    x = as.factor(sites) - .45,
    xend = as.factor(sites) + .45,
    y = Le,
    yend = Le
  ),
  colour = "black")

Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(factor(Client_Ref), 0.45) :
‘-’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(factor(Client_Ref), 0.45) :
‘+’ not meaningful for factors
```

Answer (score 4):

You could change it to a factor (moved into a pre-plotting process here) and then change it back to numeric to get the numeric value of where it's plotting on the x axis:

```r
library(tidyverse)


df <- tibble(
  sites = c(2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17),
  T1 = c(6, 2, 4, 7, 8, 6, 2, 4, 7, 8, 6, 2, 4, 5),
  T2 = c(8, 5, 6, 8, 9, 8, 5, 6, 8, 9, 8, 5, 6, 8),
  T3 = c(4, 1, 6, 3, 4, 4, 1, 6, 3, 4, 4, 1, 6, 3),
  Le = c(6.0, 2.7, 5.3, 6.0, 7.0, 6.0, 2.7, 5.3, 6.0, 7.0, 6.0, 2.7, 5.3, 5.3)
)


m_df <-  reshape2::melt(
  df,
  id.vars = c("sites", "Le"),
  variable.name = "Year",
  value.name = "value"
)

m_df %>%
  mutate(sites = factor(sites)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(sites, value, fill = Year)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "dodge",
           colour = "black") +
  geom_segment(aes(
    x = as.numeric(sites) - .45,
    xend = as.numeric(sites) + .45,
    y = Le,
    yend = Le
  ),
  colour = "black")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Edit - adding line to legend

You can add a line to the legend using `scale_linetype_manual` as follows (putting labels in as text in two places):

```r
m_df %>%
  mutate(sites = factor(sites)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(sites, value, fill = Year)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "dodge",
           colour = "black") +
  geom_segment(aes(
    x = as.numeric(sites) - .45,
    xend = as.numeric(sites) + .45,
    y = Le,
    yend = Le,
    linetype = "Benchmark"
  ),
  colour = "black") + 
  scale_linetype_manual("By site", values = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @Andy Baxter.
How would I add the segment into the legend pls? I'm finding `scale_linetype_manual` confusing.

Comment: Have added an edit with a "Benchmark" line in legend if that helps!

Comment: perfect (and so easy! :o) - thank you!